# preparing a dataset for class (applied statistics for STEM)

Tags: python, dataset

I am preparing a dataset for school and it is required to use the temperature for the last 14 days in my city as follows 102, 97, 88, 79, 82, 91, 95, 91,93, 97, 104, 106, 106, 100. I input it in and I keep getting an error code once I run it in the 3rd, 4th, and 5th screenshots need help I am doing online schooling and this is my first week in my new class I am having a hard time with it. I just don't know what I did wrong Please help thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWiU5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nErTc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJaHF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1fKv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wckV9.png)

once I run the code correctly I need to calculate descriptive statistics for the data set you entered. The pandas data frame has several methods that calculate descriptive statistics. Each method has a comment telling you what that method calculates. Needing to find the mean, median, variance, standard deviation, and description  screenshot provided

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI5jk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Column names in a `DataFrame` should be strings, not integers. You should use meaningful column names to make your code more readable and to avoid confusion.

Here is the corrected code, together with mean, median, varianc, and std cal.

```
import pandas as pd

temperatures = [102, 97, 88, 79, 82, 91, 95, 91,93, 97, 104, 106, 106, 100]

temperatures_df = pd.DataFrame(temperatures, columns=['temperature'])

print(temperatures_df)

# Calculate mean, median, variance, standard deviation
mean = temperatures_df['temperature'].mean()
median = temperatures_df['temperature'].median()
variance = temperatures_df['temperature'].var()
std_dev = temperatures_df['temperature'].std()

print("Mean:", mean)
print("Median:", median)
print("Variance:", variance)
print("Standard Deviation:", std_dev)
```